# equation reference too close to equation

Tags: equations, labels

My equation reference is appearing immediately after my equation such that it looks like I'm multiplying my first equation by (1).  How do I get the equation number to align to the right-hand-side of the page?

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:dropweight}

W_{drop} = g\frac{m_{measured}}{#\, of\, drops} = f (2\pi r) \gamma
\end{equation}

Comment: This surely is not the default. Can you provide us with your preamble as well as a single equation that replicates the result?

Comment: by default the equation number will be flush to the right edge of the text block, but also don't use math italic for multi-letter words, `{measured}` should be `{\mathrm{measured}}` and `{#\, of\, drops}` (which by default would give an error) should be  {\textrm{\# of  drops}}`

Comment: Okay, here is what I have:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:dropweight}
W_{drop} = g\frac{m_{measured}}{\#\, of\, drops} = f (2\pi r) \gamma
\end{equation}

Comment: @Lauren add it to a code block (`{}` button in the editor) in your question, code in comments doesn't work and loses all line endings and other formatting

Comment: @Lauren: As it stands it's not possible to duplicate your problem. I've voted to close this as unclear. Until you add a minimal example that replicates your problem, answers to this question is based on pure speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Your document

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:dropweight}
W_{drop} = g\frac{m_{measured}}{#\, of\, drops} = f (2\pi r) \gamma 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

generates an *error*

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
<argument> ##
             \, of\, drops
l.8 ...rop} = g\frac{m_{measured}}{#\, of\, drops}
                                                   = f (2\pi r) \gamma
?
```

After an error you should not really look at the pdf file, TeX makes no attempt to make sensible output, it just recovers to check the rest of the file.

You need `\#` for `#` but also multi-letter words should never be set in math italic (which is designed to make them look like a product of variables not a word)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:dropweight}
W_{\mathrm{drop}} = g\frac{m_{\mathrm{measured}}}{\textrm{\# of drops}} = f (2\pi r) \gamma 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

actually the error was probably from the blank line:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8 

? 
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

depending on quite how the original document looked

Comment: The OP does appear to have written `\#`, not just `#`, in the denominator. However, he does have a blank line in the `equation` environment, which will through a different error if `amsmath` is loaded.

Comment: Yep, beat me by two seconds there @Mico...

Comment: @Mico looks like a bad edit by someone else, the OPs example had `#`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Ah, I hadn't noticed that there had been an edit...

Comment: @Mico actually I'm not sure the original is a bit garbled by not beining a code block, but with `#` I get a pdf with (1) flush to the equation.....

Answer (score 0):

The subscript terms "drop" and "measured" as well as the text "# of drops" in the denominator should be all be typeset using upright-roman rather than math-italic lettering. I suggest you use `\textnormal` to typeset the terms.

If you load the `amsmath` package, you mustn't have a blank line in a displayed-math environment such as `equation`. Separately, do write `\#`, not just `#`, if you want to typeset a hashtag (aka octothorp) symbol.

Finally, I can't reproduce the issue you mentioned in the title of your posting, *viz*., the poor placement of the equation number. How wide is your text block? Please consider editing your posting to make the issue reproducible.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:dropweight}
W_{\textnormal{drop}} = g\frac{m_{\textnormal{measured}}}{\textnormal{\# of drops}} = f (2\pi r) \gamma
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can't have a blank line even without amsmath, I think the close (1) is simply that the math mode had ended (see image I just added)